# How to implement tensorflow with gpu in Windows 10?

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, deep-learning

There are many sources on configuring TensorFlow in Windows but none of them clearly states the steps and paths we should follow.

I have configured TensorFlow halfway but still I've missed few steps. Can anyone help with the whole configuration process?

I've used TensorFlow with gpu,
NVIDIA 950M, Windows 10, Python 3.5.2, CUDA nn8 v5.1

Glad even if someone could send me a link to complete process :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation in tensorflow.org has the complete process.

Comment: Thanks! Finally found some videos which will help other than the site. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pTtMEK2jtQ&t=167s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7-WPbx8VuY&t=749s